# Custom trackbar for a new Media player

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am working on a new Media Player for Windows and I have a bit of a problem with current track bars. Well, it's more of a nit pick than anything.

As they are now, trackbars behaviour are not smooth. Basically, while the song is playing, they "start. stop. start. stop. etc..." until the song finishes. How do I make it smoother so it doesn't have a start-stop effect, and just looks like it's continually moving very smoothly?

Comment: This is VERY vague. I think you need a lot more detail in this question to be taken seriously.

Comment: Show us some code. What interval did you set to your trackbar? Show use the settings of the trackbar. Generally if you set a large maximum and very small steps, lets say max 100 and step 1, then the trackbar will "run smoothly". So i would have tried to set Trackbar maximum to sound length in seconds (or even scale it more) and update the position for example every half second.